# Readings for Microsoft Office word

Tags: ms-word

I want to know why does Microsoft word don't allow multiple instance of a file. Say i have opened something.doc, once it has opened then i clicked the file something.doc again it doesn't open another instance but opens the existing instance of the file. I would love to have a concrete reading material about this. Can anyone provide? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like an issue to me but just a settings problem as illustrated on some forumns. Try doing the below hack which if for **Office 2007**:

My Computer
Tools
Folder Options
File Types
Choose XLS
Go to Advanced

Uncheck "browse in same window" in advanced window.

Then highlight Open
Edit

Make sure in the Action box it says &Open

Make sure in the application used to perform action it says:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"

Check the box next to use DDE

Remove anything that is in DDE Message box and DDE Application Not Running box.

Make sure the application box says: EXCEL

And in the Topic box it says: System